# Azure Active Directory Domain Services on premises Domain Join

Tags: azure, entra-domain-services

Please note this question is about Azure Active Directory Domain Services - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/services/active-directory-ds/

Not the similarly named Azure Active Directory - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/active-directory/

If I have an Azure site-to-site VPN to the vnet on which Azure Active Directory Domain Services is installed can I join an on premises server or client to the Azure Active Directory Domain Services domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is Yes.

Few limitations comes to my mind:

- It's preview, therefore, not covered by SLA
- Only support Flat OUs
- Only support simple GPOs
- It's a stand-alone managed domain, not an extension (can't add as new DC in an existing domain/forest)
- Does not support trust relationships
- Since it's managed by Azure ADDS, you don't have Domain Admin or Enterprise Admin privileges

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's a real shame you can't just add it to an existing domain and use standard DC replication to populate it.

Comment: You have to use Azure AD Connect to replicate on-premises to Azure AD. All objects in AAD will be available to AADDS.